# How to set the timeout on HTTPConnection under python 2.4

Tags: python

when I use HTTPConnection under python 2.4,if the serve do not answer,the connection is keeped forever.How can i break it?

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084782/timeout-for-urllib2-urlopen-in-pre-python-2-6-versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `socket.setdefaulttimeout()` and set it to a global timeout

example :

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)
```

now all httplib/urllib2 requests will have a timeout of 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use Python 2.7 and later, [HTTPConnection](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) provides a timeout parameter !

```
httplib.HTTPConnection('www.cwi.nl', 80, timeout=10)
```

(This doesn't answer this question because the OP asked for Python 2.4, but it can help others looking for that specific answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use that connection in the separate thread and join it using the desired timeout value.